# What imputation methods can be used for missing not at random covariate values in a survival analysis?

Tags: time-series, survival, data-imputation, multiple-imputation, hazard

I'm new to survival analysis and trying to understand how to use it properly. My dataset is a time series dataset where most dependent variable values are available, 2 dependent variable values are right-censored, and some covariate values are missing before a time threshold (say before 1964, so not at random, since these values were not recorded/unavailable). The imputation methods I've read about (e.g., MI) seem to handle only missing dependent variable values but not missing covariates. What would be some appropriate imputation methods to use here? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I am aware, MI methods such as Multiple Imputation by Chained Equations (MICE) or Random Forest imputation, are both methods that will allow you to impute missing values for many variables at once in your dataset. It does not matter whether they are dependent variables and covariates in your analytical models.

Basically, you use MICE to impute missing values on all variables and create many datasets, then you run your analytical models on each of these datasets, and then you pool the results according to Rubin's Rules. Most statistical software packages (R, Stata, and SAS) have well established methods for doing this.

I am most familiar with using MICE in R. Here is a good resource that will walk you through with MICE is, and how to apply it in R: http://www.stefvanbuuren.nl/publications/MICE%20in%20R%20-%20Draft.pdf

Even if you do not use R, I think that resource will still be helpful for learning about what MICE is and the practical steps one must take to impute the data.